# How to delete records which have values in specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have merged 2 dataframes, evt_df and eff_df. Evt_df contains columns like evt_id, evt_name, evt_email, eff_df contains columns like eff_id, eff_name, eff_email. I want to delete records which have values in columns which start with 'eff'.

I got:

```
EVT_ID  EVT_STATUS  EVT_VALIDFROM   EFF_ID  EFF_STATUS  EFF_VALIDFROM
ORLE-20210205   VAL 19.02.2021 12:48    ORLE-20210205   VAL 28.03.2021 12:54
ORLE-20210205   VAL 19.02.2021 12:48    ORLE-20210205   VAL 28.03.2021 12:54
ORLE-20210305   VAL 17.03.2021 15:12    ORLE-20210305   VAL 30.03.2021 09:48
ORLE-20210305   VAL 17.03.2021 15:12            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36            
ORLE-20190930   VAL 01.10.2019 12:04            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36
```

I want:

```
EVT_ID  EVT_STATUS  EVT_VALIDFROM   EFF_ID  EFF_STATUS  EFF_VALIDFROM
ORLE-20210305   VAL 17.03.2021 15:12            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36            
ORLE-20190930   VAL 01.10.2019 12:04            
ORLE-20200304   VAL 05.03.2020 18:36
```

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/PI33588/Desktop/eff_month_all.xlsx')
print(len(df.index))
df = df[(df.filter(regex='EFF', axis=1)=='').any(1)]
print(len(df.index))
```

Got;
8
0

Answer (score 0):

Run this code: `data.loc[:,data.columns.str.startswith('eff')] = None`

Here's my example:
[image]

Comment: Didnt' work. I tried: df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/PI33588/Desktop/eff_month_all.xlsx')
print(df.columns)
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('EFF_')] = None
print(df.columns)

Comment: column names are in upper case or lower case ?

Comment: With eff_ didnt work too

Comment: Weird. It does work for me. Is it possible to see your final df ?

Answer (score 0):

filter columns strating iwth eff and rows that have empty spaces

```
df[(df.filter(regex='^eff', axis=1)=='').any(1)]



evt_id evt_name evt_email eff_id eff_name eff_email
     x      xxx       xxx                          
     x      xxx       xxx                          
     x      xxx       xxx
```

Comment: I want to select columns.

Comment: what do you mean you want to select columns?Happy to help

Comment: You can add `df.style.hide_index()` if you wanted to hide index

Comment: I want to delete records which have any values in columns start with eff. Some records may be empty in evt columns and your solution will not help.

Comment: See my edit and let us know

Comment: See my edit, didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239042/discussion-between-wwnde-and-datasciencebegginer).